# link to anchor on different page and scroolTo anchor using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

How would I link to an anchor on another page but when the new page loads also scrollTo the anchor?

Below is the JQuery when my anchro link is on the same page I need to tweak it so that is also animate when the linked clicked

html:

```
<li><a href="page2.php#about-us">My Link</a></l1>
```

My JQuery:

```
$('.faq_section li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 20
    }, 600);        
});
```

Page2.php:

```
  <div id="about-us"></div>
```

Comment: you can pass the next page element id via url and read on document.ready and scroll to there

Comment: My JS knowledge is pretty limited. Would you be able to provide an example and I would be happy to accept it. Thank you for the info. I am going to do a little research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with following method

By clicking u can send some condition in URL and check that in jquery
E.g. xyz.com?p=scroll
Then in jquery on document.ready function check if 'p=scroll' is present by using indexOf. If yes then run your animate code (note. Above jquery code needs to be in output page)

Or try this http://webdeveloperswall.com/javascript/scrolling-to-different-areas-on-same-page